# mysql second ordering

Tags: mysql

my table has the following fields

```
videos
|id| |average| |views|
```

now i select some field from database, and order them by average

```
SELECT `id` from `videos` order by `average`
```

nut i need the second ordering by **"views"**, i.e. if there are two rows vith equal **"average"**, i want to order them by **"views"**.
How can i do that?
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ORDER BY `average`, `views`
```

You can order by as many fields as you wish. `DESC` can also be added after any field(s) to reverse the order.